# Forçar session a não passar de 30 minutos

Tags: php

Galera tenho um sistema de login em PHP. Eu salvo o login e a senha do usuário em uma sessão.

Inicio ela da seguinte forma:

```
// Inicia a sessão
session_start();
```

Minha dúvida e como fazer para esta sessão ter uma duração de 30 minutos, ou seja se o usuário deixar a página parada por 30 minutos a sessão tem que ser apagada.

Comment: salvar a senha do usuário em uma sessão ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu ja salvo, porém quero que seja apagado depois de 30 minutos

Comment: Não salve senha e sessão, o máximo o id do usuário que está logado ou a identificação que assim preferir, menos dados importantes!

Comment: Você pode guardar na sessão a id e uma data e hora e conforme for requisitando a página conferindo se o tempo já ultrapassou 30 minutos e fechar a sessão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `session_set_cookie_params` para "setar" um tempo de vida para a sessão

```
$time = strtotime('+30 minutes', 0);
session_set_cookie_params($time);
session_start();
```

Comment: Tem um problema aqui, nada garante que o tempo do cookie será respeitado, o usuário pode prolongar o quanto quiser. Precisa fazer um IF no servidor para garantir, mais ou menos como a outra resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```
session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['atividade']) && (time() - $_SESSION['atividade'] > 1800)) {

                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
            }
    $_SESSION['atividade'] = time();
```