# Como funciona o tempo de duração da session?

Tags: php

Galera tenho um arquivo em php com o seguinte código:

```
// Define o limitador de cache
session_cache_limiter('must-revalidate');
$cache_limiter = session_cache_limiter(); 

// Define tempo da sessão
session_cache_expire(300); 
$cache_expire = session_cache_expire();

// Inicia a sessão
session_start();
```

Com ele eu crio uma sessão com duração de 5 horas. O que eu quero saber é toda vez que eu carrego o arquivo ele atualiza a hora de expiração da sessão ou ele a matem?

Comment: Vi agora o detalhe da questão da atualização. Se fosse com `session_set_cookie_params` eu poderia dizer que depois da inicialização da sessão, o valor definido será avaliado no prazo estipulado, e não seria "renovado" quando o usuário atualizasse o browser.

Comment: O [manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-expire.php) não diz nada a respeito, mas acredito que por ser uma função, o valor é sobrescrito toda vez.

Comment: Relacionado: [Session com duração de 30 minutos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/157071/session-com-dura%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-30-minutos)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters minha dúvida continua, se eu carregar a página a sessão ganha mais 30minutos?

Comment: Eu tinha feito uma resposta, mas acabei desistindo. Não entendo muito desses assuntos de HTTP pra explicar aprofundadamente. Mas a função que você está usando só vai mudar o tempo de vida do cache do servidor, você tem que mexer no Cookie também. Com meu conhecimento, se mexer no cookie, através de `session_cookie_params` o tempo só é contado a partir da criação da sessão. Refresh não afeta a contagem.

Comment: Na verdade o tempo se mantém. Ele é relativo à session, independe de F5.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A sessão no PHP é composta por um *cookie* com um identificador, e um sistema de limpeza do lado do servidor.

## Lado do cliente

O tempo do *cookie* da sessão conta do momento **do início** desta, e mesmo que a pessoa continue acessando o site, a sessão vai vencer no tempo estipulado nas preferências, sem ser renovada automaticamente.

Se quiser prolongar a sessão para que o tempo conte do último acesso, e não do primeiro, precisa renovar o *cookie* de sessão periodicamente (ou a cada acesso).

Tem várias maneiras, esta é do próprio [manual do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-set-cookie-params.php):

```
<?php
  $lifetime=600; // EM SEGUNDOS
  session_start();
  setcookie(session_name(),session_id(),time()+$lifetime);
?>
```

Outra delas, retirada [deste site](http://brian.moonspot.net/2008/05/14/php-session-cookie-refresh/) também é um bom exemplo:

```
Setcookie(
    ini_get("session.name"),
    session_id(),
    time()+ini_get("session.cookie_lifetime"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_path"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_domain"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_secure"),
    ini_get("session.cookie_httponly")
);
```

#### Cookie "da" sessão vs. cookie "de" sessão, e a questão das sessões "demoradas".

(não é terminologia técnica, só pus as aspas pela semântica)

A terminologia é meio confusa, mas existe também o que chamamos de "cookie de sessão" (do ponto de vista do navegador, não confundir com o termo sessão do PHP) - que é quando você cria o cookie com tempo "zero". Neste caso, as implementações atuais dos navegadores procuram manter o cookie no navegador até que você encerre a sessão de navegação (fechando o browser).

O lado "bom" é que você não precisa renovar o tempo nesse caso, o cookie dura enquanto não fechar o browser. Porém, do lado do do servidor, continua a questão da expiração (leia mais abaixo sobre o lado do servidor).

No fim, se precisar de coisas mais duradouras, acaba sendo muito melhor você criar um cookie convencional no cliente (com um Token) e usar esse token para começar sempre uma sessão nova já logado, em vez de fazer "malabarismos" para ter sessões longas no PHP (que vão ficar ocupando disco à toa e criando problemas para uma grande maioria de sessões que nunca vão ser reestabelecidas)

## Lado do servidor

Não se esqueça que de qualquer forma, este valor do `php.ini` precisa ser maior do que o tempo da sessão. Se tiver uma sessão de 2 horas, use por exemplo 7800 ( 2h * 60m * 60s = 7200, mais 600 pra dar 10 minutos de "folga"):

No `php.ini`:

```
session.gc_maxlifetime = 7800
```

Pode até usar `ini_set`, mas se tiver qualquer outra página usando cookie, com um tempo menor de gc, de nada vai adiantar, pois vai contar o tempo menor. Se não tiver acesso ao `php.ini` convém setar o [`gc_maxlifetime`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)  e o [`session_save_path`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-save-path.php)

Comment: Importante notar que é pra por isso em todas as páginas que usam session_start, melhor até já colocar num include.

Comment: entendo, mas se eu ficar renovando o cookie o servidor não vai apagar os arquivos?

Comment: o mecanismo do cookie é no browser, o session start cuida do lado do servidor.

Comment: o '$lifetime=600' é em minutos?

Comment: Segundos. No exemplo acima é a hora atual + 600 segundos. Notar que me ative à questão do cookie renovar a sessão, mas os detalhes é bom ver na documentação do setcookie para entender melhor e adaptar ao seu caso. E não esqueça de acertar no ini do PHP pra duração da sessão ser igual ou maior do que o valor do cookie.